# avconv framerate not encoding

Tags: linux, video, encoding, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I'm attempting to encode a video from a folder of .png's using avconv. I have 480 images and I want the video to encode at a framerate of 240 fps. I'm entering the following code. What I think I should be getting is a 2 second video. Instead I'm getting a 19 second video, which suggests that it's encoding at its default setting, 25 fps.

```
avconv -f image2 -i %04d.png -c:v libx264 -r 240 -s hd720 -crf 21 video03.mkv
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include the full, uncut command line output from that command.